# Passing data from Child to Parent Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

How can I query and access a specific field on Contacts to then help me populate a Visualforce page I have on the Account?

Details:

- I have a Visualforce page on my Contact that simply displays an alert if our field "Special_Care_Comments__c" is not blank.
- I'd like to roll this up to the Account level too. So, if any Contact on the Account has their "Special_Care_Comments__c" field filled in, I want to display the same type of simple alert popup on the Account.

This is my Contact VF page:

```
 <apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var specialCareMessage = "{!Contact.Special_Care_Comments__c}";

        if( specialCareMessage !== "" ) {
            alert( "SPECIAL CARE COMMENTS: "+ specialCareMessage);
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

How can I query all Contacts belonging to the Account, and, if possible, concatenate the values in this special care comments field to display in the alert popup?

Comment: You're going to need a [VIsualforce controller extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) that performs a [SOQL parent-child query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) using the relationship name `Contacts`. Your controller extension can perform the concatenation and return data to the page.

Comment: Okay, good, that's what I thought. Would you be able to provide me an example though?

Comment: I do not have an example to hand, but this is a pretty simple build that I think you can get through with the docs and Trailhead. You can ask further questions when you get stuck.

Comment: @DavidReed No Apex Code necessary for this one.

Answer (score 1):

For the account page, you can use some standard controller logic, like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <script>
      var messages = [], item;
      <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="Contact">
        item = "{!JSENCODE(Contact.Special_Care_Comments__c)}";
        if(item) {
          messages.push(item);
        }
      </apex:repeat>
      if(messages.length) {
        alert(messages.join('\n'));
      }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

If you want deduplication, etc, you'll have to figure that out on your own.